# Installing ubuntu alongside windows 10 and freedos

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

My laptop came with freeDOS. I have already installed Windows 10 on my laptop alongside freeDOS. I now want to install Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10. I also want to remove freeDOS but I am not sure which partition it is installed on. Here are my partitions:

[image: Partitions]

Please suggest the steps to remove DOS and install Ubuntu. I have shrunk the size of the C:\ drive and made a new partition F:\ specially for Ubuntu. Please suggest the further steps.
Also, while installing Ubuntu it gives the option of installing alongside freeDOS but it does not give the option to install alongside Windows 10 and I don't know why.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your 1 TB hard drive - i am not seeing enough space to install Ubuntu Linux...you need at least 10 GB of space. Is this screen before or after?

Comment: i intend to install ubuntu on F: drive(48 GB) which is completely free. All my other drives also have free space of more than 200 GB.

Comment: Also can you suggest if its safe to delete the FAT32 drive which i think has the freeDOS on it.

Comment: How you are dual booting into FreeDOS or Windows? Make F: as unallocated  or in other words not FAT32

Comment: Always backup before deleting anything. But Make sure Windows fast start up is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the "something else" option (manual option) in the installation GUI.

Then you have to format ext4 the partition where you're going to install ubuntu and mount it as "/" (root). As for the bootloader I think that grub2 will automatically install if you have a BIOS/MBR machine..